# Find and update an element in a Java Queue

Tags: data-structures

Trying to work on small use case where i have to add string of websites in a queue. if the site repeats then i have to update the numberofVisits+1. Else i would add that object into the queue. Something wrong with updateCount code. Please let me know

here is the code snippet. I am unable to move forward on this.

```
public CLassName(String url, int numVisits) {
        this.url = url;
        this.numVisits = numVisits;
}
    public int getNumVisits() {
        return this.numVisits;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return this.url;
    }
    public void setNumVisits(int updatedNumVisits) {
        this.numVisits = updatedNumVisits;
    }

private static Queue<ClassName> sites = new LinkedList<ClassName>();

    // Method to find the website in the queue and increment the visited count by 1, adding new node in case website is not found

public static void update(String url) {

//code should go in here. // THis is wrong code

if (sites.isEmpty()) sites.add(new ClassName(url,1));
         while(!sites.isEmpty()) {
             String tmpUrl = sites.peek().getUrl();
             int numVisits = sites.peek().getNumVisits();
            if(tmpUrl!=null && tmpUrl.equalsIgnoreCase(url)) {
                sites.add(new ClassName(tmpUrl,numVisits+1));
            } else if(tmpUrl!=null){
                sites.add(new ClassName(tmpUrl,numVisits));
            } else {
                sites.add(new ClassName(url,1));
            }
         }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] visitedSites = { "www.google.co.in", "www.google.co.in", "www.facebook.com", "www.upgrad.com", "www.google.co.in", "www.youtube.com",
                "www.facebook.com", "www.facebook.com", "www.google.co.in", "www.microsoft.com", "www.9gag.com", "www.netflix.com",
                "www.netflix.com", "www.9gag.com", "www.microsoft.com", "www.amazon.com", "www.amazon.com", "www.uber.com", "www.amazon.com",
                "www.microsoft.com" };

        for (String url : visitedSites) {
            update(url);
        }
```

Comment: first; in update method, if sites is empty then add the url with initial 1 visit number, then return/exit the update method, second when you found that url is already exist there then increment the existing, do not create new one and add again.

Comment: How do loop through the Queue if i don't add or remove ?

Comment: When you get an item in the queue with sites.peek(), and if it is what you are looking  for, then just do put-peek-var-name-here.incNumVisits(), but you need to add incNumVisit method first to the your class. then you do not need create/remove/add steps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the recommendation. I did a small tweek to address the problem.

1. I did not add Dummy site
2. Added a counter and incremented so that it is always < the size of  queue

Here is my solution and it works

```
public static void update(Queue<String> sites,String url,int numberOfVisits) 
        {
            if ( sites.isEmpty())  sites.add(url); // first time

            boolean flag = false;
            int counter = 0
            while (!sites.empty && counter<sites.size()) //go over all the urls in the queue 
            {
                if (sites.head().equalsIgnoreCase(url))
                {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
                sites.insert(sites.remove()); //removing the head and inserting it to the end of the queue
                  counter ++;
            }

            if (!flag==true) {
                numberOfVisits=numberOfVisits+1;
            }
            else {
                sites.insert(url);   
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

the update method just could be like this;

```
        boolean increased = false;
        Iterator<ClassName> statIterator = sites.iterator();
        while (statIterator.hasNext()) {
            ClassName st = statIterator.next();
            if (st.getUrl().equals(url)) {
                st.setNumVisits(st.getNumVisits()+1);
                increased = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!increased) {
            sites.add(new ClassName(url,1));
        }
```